# Unexpected KeyError in Flask (Python) when checking for key in json dict

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, flask

this is my first question on StackOverflow and I have been stumped by a KeyError for the longest time so I hope someone is able to figure out what's wrong. I am making a Flask app which has some POST methods (from AJAX), and my line of Python code checking if the key is in the dict   `if 'delete' in data` is giving me a KeyError.  I tried printing but it isn't printing my output either which is weird. This is the Python code:

```
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'addItem' in request.form:
            # Do stuff

        elif request.get_json():
            data = request.get_json()
            print(data) # This is not printing even though I can see the object in Chrome devtools
            
            if 'delete' in data: # This is the line throwing the error
                to_remove = data['delete']
                session['ingredients'].remove(to_remove)
                session.modified = True
                return redirect('/')
            elif 'name' in data:
                # Do stuff
```

And this is the Javascript/jQuery for the two types of JSON objects:

```
    $('.save').on('click', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'name': $(event.target).siblings(".edit[name='name']").text(),
                'key_ingred': $(event.target).siblings(".edit[name='key-ingred']").text(),
                'recipe': $(event.target).siblings(".edit[name='recipe']").text(),
                'meal': $(event.target).siblings('b').text(),
                'date': $(event.target).siblings('.date').text()
            }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    })

    $('.delete').on('click', function(event){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'delete': $(event.target).prev().text() }),
            success: function() { $(event.target).parent().remove(); },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        $(event.target).parent().remove();
    });
```

EDIT: Here is the full traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Project/app.py", line 40, in index
    if 'delete' in data:
KeyError: 'delete'
```

I have tried using `if data.get('delete') is not None` as well and that didn't work either.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: added the traceback message!

Comment: why do you have elif request.get_json():

Comment: On that HTML file I have one instance of POST which is from a form, and 2 others which are JSON. So I'm checking to see which type of POST request it is

Comment: This is really odd.  Can you try `print(type(data))`?

Comment: That doesn't print either :(

Comment: Stranger and stranger.  Do you have an old `.pyc` file hanging around, that is somehow being executed instead of the `.py` file?